# Simple JQuery function will not execute after form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Simple JQuery function will not execute after form submission. I can see that my form values are sent but when function in reached, there is no execution.  I've read several posts and removed the "submit" value from my button id and still JQuery will work.  Any help direction would be greatly appreciated.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  //When the chat form is submitted
  $("#chatform").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    //Take the values directly form the chat form//
    var name = $("#uname").val();
    var message = $("#message").val();


    if (message != "" && name != "") {
      $.post("clashofcolchatdata.php", {
        message: message,
        name: name
      }, function(data) {
        $("#chat_space").append(data);
      });
    } else {
      alert("Data missing");
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="chatform" action="">
  <div id="chat_comform">

    <!-- This is the blank space for the chat -->
    <div id="chat_space">
    </div>

    <div id="chat_message">
      <!--Name | Name of the user entering the message  -->
      <input type="text" placeholder=" Name" name="uname" id="uname" style="color:black" required/>
      <br />

      <!--Message | This is the chat message -->
      <input type="text" placeholder=" Enter your chat message" name="message" id="message" style="color:black" required/>

      <!-- This disables the button if anything on the is still invalid -->
      <button type="submit" id="chat_submit" name="formsub" value="post" style="color:black">Submit</button>
    </div>
  </div>

</form>
```

Comment: `$("#chatform")` selects an element with the ID `chatform` and I don't see any such beast

Comment: I changed the form name to form id="chatform" and it still does not execute

Comment: Yes it does: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/wt6aLgpm/

Comment: @ChrisG I don't see where it is executing on the fiddle.  As well I don't see any output, it just wipes the entered values upon submit.  The same thing that my code does.

Comment: @Skip It doesn't wipe the values because it properly intercepts the form submission. Then the `$.post` runs (and obviously does nothing but produce a 404 on jsfiddle), as can be observed in the console. If the entered text disappears for you it means there's still something wrong with your JS code, and the browser sends the form. Since `action` is blank, this simply causes a page reload, clearing the inputs.

Comment: @ChrisG thanks for your help, even though I can see the code execute in the debugger or the variables populate, I thank you for your time and insight

Answer (score 3):

change `<form name="chatform">`
to `<form id="chatform">`. You're querying by html id when you do `$('#chatform')` but you have not set an id on the form.

Comment: changed form name to form id and it still doesn't work